# mod_rewrite keeps anchor link

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, anchor

I want `example.com/site/about#whoami` to be redirected to `example.com/site/?page=about#whoami` using mod_rewrite directives, but I have no idea on how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: Anchor character `#` may be passed, but it has no effect on the substitution URL unless the redirection is to a page where the anchor exists. Although Apache cannot do the scrolling of the window down to the anchor, the browser will do it in that case. Here is some [Apache information about redirecting anchors](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#redirectanchors)

You may try something like this:

```php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)/?   site?page=$1  [NC,NE,L]
```

Maps

`http://example.com/site/anything`

To

`http://example.com/site/?page=anything`

String `site` is assumed to be fixed.

String `anything` may contain an anchor `#` and it will be passed in the substitution URL.

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it. I've tested and it still scrolls down the page to the anchor :D